# How can I use JSLint for a segment of code which depends on JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jslint

I'm relatively new to Javascript, and I'd like to run the piece of code I spent the weekend playing with through JSLint so that it can point out where I was being a total idiot :)

Unfortunately, I get tons of errors about missing function declarations, which are part of the JQuery javascript library and various plugins for it.

Is there any way I can run such code through JSLint?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using the web version of [jslint](http://www.jslint.com/), you can simply add the `$` object in the predefined option:

[image]

If you're using a local copy of jslint, you'd want to set the `predef` option to `$` in the `options` object.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Daniel's answer, you can "declare" `$` on a per-file basis by including the following comment:

```
/*global $*/
```

(Note: no space is allowed between `/*` and `global`.)

For web stuff you'll often also want to include `window`, i.e.

```
/*global $, window*/
```