# JSLint - Undeclared 'jQuery' warning

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint, jshint

I am trying to make the following jQuery code JSLint compliant.

```
(function ($) {
   "use strict";
    $('.addition').click(function () {
        $('.textbox:last,.addition:last,.subtraction:last,.replace:last').clone(true).appendTo('.replace:last');
        $('.textbox:last').val("");
        $('.addition:not(:last),.subtraction:not(:last)').attr('disabled','true');
    });

    $('.subtraction').click(function () {

        if($('.replace').length === 1) {
            $('.subtraction').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        } else {
            $('.textbox:last,.addition:last,.subtraction:last,.replace:last').remove();
            $('.addition:last,.subtraction:last').removeAttr('disabled');
        }   
    });     
}(jQuery));
```

My code is working fine. I am just trying to clear the JSLint warnings. I do not understand why JSLint is giving me an `undeclared 'jQuery'` warning on line `}(jQuery));` (last line).

**UPDATE** 
Declaring jQuery as a global variable has cleared the warning.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use JSLint for a segment of code which depends on JQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920012/how-can-i-use-jslint-for-a-segment-of-code-which-depends-on-jquery)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're using jslint.com, you'll need to add jQuery to Global variables under options

Comment: Thanks. That cleared the warning. Do you know why this is necessary?

Comment: np... jslint parses the code without assumptions or which variables are global unless you set them in the options section.

Comment: @user3421311 If you don't tell JSLint what variables come from another scope, it has to assume that you haven't properly declared something. That is, JSLint goes one file at a time and can't tell the difference between, if you have `var spam = "ham";`, whether `sapm = "spiced ham";` is a misspelling or `sapm` is from a parent scope -- unless you tell it *and* your fellow programmers. And that's why it's useful.

Comment: "$ = jQuery" to be more specific.

Comment: where are these jslint options you speak of?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jslint.com, you need to replace 1st line of your code. you need to add "global jQuery" as a comment line. See here..

**replace:**
(function ($) {

**by using:**
/*global jQuery */
jQuery(function ($) {
.....

All the Best. 
Puspendu Mondal